# How do I open a file with vim from cmd?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, vim

I'm using windows 7.

Unix I can open a file in vi with by using:

```
vi textFile.txt
```

In windows I want to navigate to the folder and type what I have above.

What is the best way to go about this?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Related post - [How do you run Vim in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10049316/465053)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly `vi` isn't installed by default and is not available on windows. A very good emulation of vi is available called `vim`, I assume for the rest of this that you have vim installed.

What you want to do is launch `vim.exe` from the command line without specifying the full path to the file. To do that you need to add the full path to the file's containing folder to the `PATH` environment variable. Here's how to do that:

Go to `computer` in windows explorer. Then right click on the background and select `properties` This should bring you to the system folder of the control panel.

In the left hand pane click `Advanced system settings`, click the environment variables button at the bottom of the new window that pops up.

The top pane of this window should be titled `User variables for <Your Username>`. Scroll through this list of user variables, and find one named `path` (capitalisation not important) and edit it. If there isn't a path variable on the list, then click the new button under the list to create a new variable, and name it path.

If you're creating a new path variable, simply paste the path to the containing folder as the value of the user variable. if you're editing an existing path variable you need to add a semi-colon `;` character immediately followed by the path to your vim installation. the path to your vim instalation proably looks something like this: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74`

Restart your command line tool after you have done this. Now you should be able to use `vim` similarly to how you would use `vi`.

Comment: I can confirm that this solution still works with window 10 for vim 8.2. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. This is fairly core to windows.

Answer (score 4):

During Vim (for Win32) install, you have the option to install batch files for launching vim from the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

On my system it works, the syntax is the same:

```
C:\>vim somefile.txt
```

Make sure vim is in your path.  Make sure you select the console and GUI versions when installing (I think this is the default now).

Comment: What needs to be in my path for windows? Vim.exe?