# How can I add configuration file to Nano obtained from WinGet on WIndows?

Tags: windows, powershell, gnu, nano, winget

I have installed [this version of Nano](https://winget.run/pkg/GNU/Nano) using:

```
winget install GNU.nano
```

Now, I'm trying to figure out where to put the config files for nano to read them. Below is the list of places where I've tried putting the file:

- `%ProgramData%`\`.nanorc`
- `%ProgramData%`\`nano.rc`
- `%UserProfile%`\`.nanorc`
- `%UserProfile%`\`nano.rc`
- `%UserProfile%`\`Documents`\`.nanorc`
- `%UserProfile%`\`Documents`\`nano.rc`
- `%LocalAppData%`\`Microsoft`\`WinGet`\`Packages`\`GNU.Nano_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe`\`.nanorc`
- `%LocalAppData%`\`Microsoft`\`WinGet`\`Packages`\`GNU.Nano_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe`\`nano.rc`

*PS: I used `set tabsize 4` as my test config. Also, `nano -T 4 ./file` works fine.*

Comment: Put your config files in c:\programdata

Comment: @John That also didn't work

Comment: Try C:\Users\jusername\Documents

Comment: @John Didn't work either

Comment: Thanks. What this means is that your program is incompatible with Windows.  The locations I gave you are bland neutral locations.

Comment: @John Can an official WinGet package be incompatible with Windows though?

Comment: If must be, else the locations provided (very standard Windows) would work.

Answer (score 1):

To install Nano properly on Windows, please follow [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1699078/116221).

From the Nano docs themselves:

```bash
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Notes:
#       1. Whith normal shell privilege, .nanorc is loaded from:
#          "%USERPROFILE%\.nanorc"
#
#       2. With Administrator privilege, .nanorc is loaded from:
#      "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\.nanorc".
#
#       3. The systemwide nanorc is loaded from:
#          "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\nanorc".
#
#       4. In Windows-10, the locations are:
#                       ALLUSERSPROFILE   C:\ProgramData
#                       USERPROFILE       C:\Users\<username>
```

Make sure to add this to your "User" and "Machine" (*System*) PATHs.

Answer (score 0):

Put `nano.rc` file from installation directory to your `$HOME` directory ( C:\users\username)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've already tried that and it didn't work. I've listed that above as `%UserProfile%\nano.rc`